# How to Set the text for an iMenuItem (in code) using Android Studio?

Tags: android, andengine

Please help, I am trying to set the text of a IMenuItem, this is my code:

**cantidadUnoItem = new ScaleMenuItemDecorator(new TextMenuItem(7, resourcesManager.cantidadUnoFont, cantUno , vbom), 1.2f, 1);**

in “cantUno" there is stored text which, when you click the MenuItem, then the variable is updated but the text is not updated on the MenuItem.

For example before clicking the MenuItem, my code shows:

**cantidadUnoItem = new ScaleMenuItemDecorator(new TextMenuItem(7, resourcesManager.cantidadUnoFont, *“ON”* , vbom), 1.2f, 1);**

after you click:

**cantidadUnoItem = new ScaleMenuItemDecorator(new TextMenuItem(7, resourcesManager.cantidadUnoFont, *“OFF”* , vbom), 1.2f, 1);**

in a variable of type Text can be stead with the following code:

**var.setText("New");**

But I cannot see that value appear in the MenuItem.

English is not my primary language, please feel free to ask for clarification using the comments.